# Add Alert programmatically sharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, alert

how to add alert programmatically for current user.
I tried this code but it alway say :

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertCollection dont have Add() function

this the code :

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://serverName:22222/sites/TestSite/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Shared Documents");
                    SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(@"domainName\userName");
                    var newAlert = user.Alerts.Add();
                    newAlert.Title = "My Custom Alert";
                    newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.List;
                    newAlert.List = list;
                    newAlert.DeliveryChannels = SPAlertDeliveryChannels.Email;
                    newAlert.EventType = SPEventType.Add;
                    newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
                    newAlert.Update();
                }
            }
```

Any ideas , and if there is a way to do it whith COM.